# Generating a SAN CSR in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, csr

I am currently writing a script to generate CSRs through a web interface for submission to generate a certificate. My current issue is that I want to generate a SAN certificate but I can't find any information on how to add the `subjectAlternateName` into the generated certificate request.

My current code is:

```
$private_key = openssl_pkey_new( array( 'private_key_bits' => 2048 ) );
$domain_data = [
    "countryName"            => 'GB',
    "stateOrProvinceName"    => 'Countyname',
    "localityName"           => 'townname',
    "organizationName"       => 'Company ltd.',
    "organizationalUnitName" => "IT",
    "emailAddress"           => 'IT@example.com',
    "commonName"             => 'example.com',
];
$config_args = ['private_key_bits' => 2048];
$attributes = [];

$csr = openssl_csr_new( $domain_data, $private_key, $config_args, $attributes );

openssl_csr_export( $csr, $csr_out );
```

Adding `subjectAlternateName` into the `$domain_data` array doesn't appear to add anything into the CSR when I parse it later.

Is it possible to do this directly in PHP?

Comment: Da codez, plz! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: I dont think this is possible. Read this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by generating a temporary copy of my `openssl.cnf` file with the `subjectAltName` line injected into it. This config can then be loaded by setting `$config_args['config'] = $temporaryfilepath`

Comment: i vote -1. in a shell using opoenssl yes its ok. But using php, are you sure you did it ? where is the config file ? 
this is not an answer anyway ...