# Generate CSR with subjectAltName extension

Tags: php, openssl, csr

I'm currently using the following code to generate CSRs with `subjectAltName` for additional domains.

```
$domains = ["example.com", "www.example.com"];

$san = implode(",", array_map(function ($dns) {
        return "DNS:" . $dns;
}, $domains));

$csr = openssl_csr_new([
    "CN" => reset($domains),
    "ST" => "Germany",
    "C" => "DE",
    "O" => "Unknown",
    "subjectAltName" => $san,
], $privateKey, [
    "digest_alg" => "sha256",
    "req_extensions" => "v3_req",
]);
```

But when I use `openssl req -text -noout -verify -in csr.pem` to verify the generated CSR, the `subjectAltName` is not listed under the `Requested Extensions` section. Instead, `subjectAltName` is added to the subject.

`subjectAltName` is recognized in the first array, other arbitrary values result in an error. But how can I create a CSR in PHP with OpenSSL that really includes the `subjectAltName` as requested extension?

This question is specifically about the bundled `openssl_*` functions, not any third party library like `phpseclib`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a SAN CSR in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33755758) and [How do you get the subjectAltName from a CSR in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982778/how-do-you-get-the-subjectaltname-from-a-csr-in-php). Also see [Adding subjectAltName to csr using phpseclib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29650036)

Comment: @jww: "Generating a SAN CSR in PHP" is the only duplicate here. And the answer here is way better than the other one there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been messing with this since the upvote and can't find an elegant solution, but I did find a workaround that might work for you.  As you probably know, you can specify the alt names in the openssl config file.  You can also specify your own config file in the `configArgs` to `openssl_csr_new`

Combining these two, you could create/modify an openssl config file in a writable directory at runtime, like /tmp/, and then tell use it.

The relevant bit of code in your openssl_csr_new call looks like:

```
"digest_alg" => "sha256",
"req_extensions" => "v3_req",
"config" => "/path/to/config/file" // <-- new line
```

In the config file, you'll need to set the v3_req section up to use the alt names that will be in the file, e.g.

```
subjectAltName = @test_req
```

Then (re)create the test_req section, and populate it with your DNS names, e.g.

```
[ test_req ]
DNS.1 = foo.bar
DNS.2 = foo.baz
```

If you need more information, let me know.  Maybe someone else can figure out how to shoehorn it into the php function directly, but this might be an openssl limitation.

Comment: Oh, you must also delete the `subjectAltName` array entry in your existing code, it won't be used, all it's doing is messing up your subject line.

Comment: You need a minimum config file, it's now implemented here: https://github.com/kelunik/acme/commit/dcce0e6e9fba0809dc4d296e115a8acf0a2c0f86